# Regex validation in java and java scipt for email address

Tags: java, javascript, regex, email-validation

We are using below regular expression to validate email address in java `^[\\w!#\\$'\\*\\+=\\?\\^\\/_~-]+(\\.[\\w!#\\$'\\*\\+=\\?\\^\\/_~-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$` and it worked fine with invalid email address `raju.rathi@gmail.com&^(*&^(*^2` but when I use the same regular expression in javascript , it doesn't work and failes with even valid email addresses . Please suggest what could be root cause of this mismatch?

for e.g. in javascript , I'm getting false value with below test conditional -

> /^[\w!#\$'\*\+=\?\^\/*~-]+(\.[\w!#\$'\*\+=\?\^\/*~-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+
>   [A-Z]{2,4}$/.test("raju.rathi@gmail.com")

Comment: Why don't you use a dedicated API for this (mailapi)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: sorry but it is not a duplicate . i can google and get regex from internet but my requirement is to use same regrx as used in java program which is not working .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert `\\` to `\` in Javascript regex literal:

```
/^[\w!#$'*+=?^\/~-]+(\.[\w!#$'*+=?^\/~-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test("raju.rathi@gmail.com")
```

Also many special regex characters like `$`, `+`, `*`  etc. don't need to be escaped inside character class hence I have removed unnecessary escaping from your character class.

Comment: /^[\w!#$'*+=?^\/~-]+(\.[\w!#$'*+=?^\/~-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/.test("raju.rathi@gmail.com") - still i'm getting false when i ran this in java script console

Comment: **[It works here](http://regex101.com/r/eD6lW1/1)** Make sure you use `i` (ignore case) flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})$/.test('raju.rathi@gmail.com');
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    var flag = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})$/.test('raju.rathi@gmail.com');
  </script>
  <h5><script>document.write(flag)</script></h5>
</body>

</html>
```